# Function to fit ARIMAX Models with rsplit Object

Tags: time-series

I would like to ask for help to resolve my issue.
The function has to fit ARIMAX Models and provide predictions.
My goal is to apply rolling origin on dataset, fit the model with analysis set 
and get predictions from the assessment set. I have to extract all the predictions of assessment set,
so that I could get prediction fast for the whole year. 
How can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)
library(fable)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(rsample)


grim_1<-data.frame(
          Datum_ab = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00"),to= as.POSIXct("2000-12-31 00:00"), by = "hour"),
          Temp_Ist=rnorm(n = 8761, mean = 15, sd = 5),
           Summe = rnorm(n = 8761, mean = 200, sd = 10) )


lg_id <- rep("GRIM_1", 8761)
grim_1 <- cbind(grim_1, lg_id)
my_data_tsbl <- as_tsibble(grim_1, key = lg_id, index = Datum_ab)


roll_eem_sliding <-rsample::rolling_origin(data=my_data_tsbl, initial = 365, assess= 120, skip = 120, cumulative = FALSE)
mod_form_1 <- as.formula(Summe ~ Temp_Ist + pdq(6,0,7) + PDQ(0,1,1, period= "day"))


ff_rolling_flex <- function(split, formula) {

  split_for_data <- analysis(split)

  ff_model <-split_for_data%>% 
    as_tsibble() %>%
    fable::ARIMA(formula)

  holdout <- assessment(split)

  out <- broom::augment(ff_model, newdata = holdout)%>%
    # calculate residuals for future use
    mutate(.resid = Summe - .fitted)

  # Return the test data set with the additional columns
  out
}

ff_rolling_flex(roll_eem_sliding$splits[[1]], mod_form_1) 
#> Error in match.arg(ic): 'arg' muss NULL sein oder ein Charakter-Vektor.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `tsibble` package has its own functions for creating splits which are recognized by the `fable` package, so you don't need to use the `rsample` functions here.

In this case, I think what you are trying to do is equivalent to tiling in the `tsibble` terminology -- where you train on a window of fixed length and the windows do not overlap. Alternatives are stretching (with an expanding training set) and sliding (with fixed length training sets that overlap).

To simplify the MWE, I've reduced the size of the data set and the size of the model.

The following code will fit models to each window, produce forecasts for the following window, and produce a summary of the forecast accuracy.

```r
library(tsibble)
library(fable)
#> Loading required package: fabletools

set.seed(77)
my_data_tsbl <- tibble(
  Datum_ab = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00"), to = as.POSIXct("2000-01-30 00:00"), by = "hour"),
  Temp_Ist = rnorm(n = length(Datum_ab), mean = 15, sd = 5),
  Summe = rnorm(n = length(Datum_ab), mean = 200, sd = 10),
  lg_id = rep("GRIM_1", length(Datum_ab))
) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = lg_id, index=Datum_ab)

tiled <- tile_tsibble(my_data_tsbl, .size=120)

ff_model <- tiled %>%
  model(
    arima = ARIMA(Summe ~ 1 + Temp_Ist + pdq(1, 0, 1) + PDQ(0, 0, 1, period = "day"))
  )
ff_forecast <- forecast(ff_model, new_data=tiled)
ff_forecast
#> # A fable: 697 x 7 [1h] <?>
#> # Key:     .id, lg_id, .model [6]
#>      .id lg_id  .model Datum_ab            Summe .distribution Temp_Ist
#>    <int> <chr>  <chr>  <dttm>              <dbl> <dist>           <dbl>
#>  1     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 00:00:00  200. N(200,  95)       12.3
#>  2     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 01:00:00  201. N(201,  97)       20.5
#>  3     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 02:00:00  200. N(200,  98)       18.2
#>  4     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 03:00:00  199. N(199,  99)       20.2
#>  5     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 04:00:00  199. N(199,  99)       15.8
#>  6     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 05:00:00  201. N(201, 100)       20.7
#>  7     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 06:00:00  201. N(201, 100)       10.1
#>  8     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 07:00:00  201. N(201, 100)       14.3
#>  9     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 08:00:00  200. N(200, 101)       15.7
#> 10     1 GRIM_1 arima  2000-01-01 09:00:00  200. N(200, 101)       22.2
#> # … with 687 more rows
ff_forecast %>% accuracy(my_data_tsbl)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 10
#>   .model lg_id  .type      ME  RMSE   MAE    MPE  MAPE  MASE    ACF1
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 arima  GRIM_1 Test  -0.0107  9.69  7.71 -0.239  3.87 0.709 -0.0410
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The column of `ff_forecast` named `Summe` is the mean of the forecast distribution. The distribution itself is given in `.distribution`.

To parallelize the computation, the `future` package can be used by inserting  `plan(multiprocess)` before the modelling.

Comment: Hello Prof. Hyndman. Thank you so much for your help. Your solution is great. The ff_forecast contain a column .distribution. Is there another way to get predicted values of "Summe". Sorry for my next question. What does "1" in your equation  arima = ARIMA(Summe ~ 1 + Temp_Ist + pdq(1, 0, 1) + PDQ(0, 0, 1, period = "day")) mean? Thank you a lot.

Comment: The 1 means include the constant. The mean of the forecast distribution is also provided in `ff_forecast`.

Comment: I am very sorry that I have to ask you again. But I have tried to extract the mean of the forecast with  ggplot2::fortify(ff_forecast, level = 95) and I am still  unable to obtain the forecasted values. My second issue is that I have to parallelize the forecasting. How could I apply package future or furrr? Thank you very much for your help and your great work. With best regards.

Comment: Thank you a lot Prof. Hyndman. I am sorry I had to read documentation more carefully. When I fit two models with my data with  `plan(multiprocess)

ff_model <- tiled %>%
  model(
    arima = ARIMA(Summe ~ 1+ Temp_Ist + pdq(6, 0, 7) + PDQ(0, 1, 1, period = "day")),
    autoarima = ARIMA(Summe ~ 1+Temp_Ist)
  )

ff_forecast <- forecast(ff_model, new_data=tiled)

ff_model%>%
  select(autoarima)`  I get null autoarima model and get Error: The result is not a valid mable. The key variables must uniquely identify each row. Thank you a lot. I excuse me for my questions.

Comment: You need to select the key variables as well.

Comment: Hello Prof. Hyndman. I have fitted auto.arima model with my data but got null model? What am I doing wrong?  Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Fitting an inappropriate model for the data.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, `Summe`  is the mean of the forecast distributions. If you only want point forecasts, use these. Pearson correlations are not an appropriate way to evaluate forecasts. See http://OTexts.com/fpp3 for information about forecasting using fable and how to evaluate forecasts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 
I have 16 datasets like "my_data_tsbl". I try: `foo2<-rbind(my_data_tsbl_1, my_data_tsbl_2)
by_lg <- foo2 %>%
  group_by(lg_id)%>%
  nest()
try_model <- function (df){  
  tiled <- tile_tsibble(df, .size=365)  
  ff_model <- tiled %>%
    model(
      arima = ARIMA(Summe ~ 1 + Temp_Ist + pdq(6, 0, 7) + PDQ(0, 1, 1, period = "day")),
      autoarima = ARIMA(Summe)
    )%>% 
    forecast(new_data=tiled)
} ff_models<-by_lg %>%
mutate(mod = data %>% map(try_model))`
but I get Error in UseMethod("key_data") : 
  no applicable method for 'key_data'